# Okular 20.12.3 does not open pdf after compilation in LyX (permissions issue?)

Tags: permissions, okular, lyx

After updating okular from version 1.3.3 to okular 20.12.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS it can can't open pdf after it's compiled in LyX 2.3.6.1 (after clicking View button). Error message: "Could not open file:///var/lib/snapd/void/sample.pdf" (sample.lyx is the source file). Directory '/var/lib/snapd/void' really exists. Probably it has to do with insufficient permissions of okular (I can open pdf files in my home folder)? It was installed using Ubuntu Software GUI (I guess with snap which installs programs with minimal permissions). I tried apt install, but it installs only okular 1.3.3. Installing latest version of okular with apt may probably be a solution or installing it's deb file directly (didn't find it).

Older version of okular 1.3.3 and evince open compiled pdf-s without any problems.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared because of permission restrictions of okular, installed through snap. After changing the temporary directory of Lyx (Menu [Tools]->[Preferences]->[Paths]) from `/tmp` to `/home/...` everything works.